# How to know array is the last array being delete

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView in a containerView that have a title and a button in collectionViewCell, if the button is pressed i remove item in array. The case is if all item in array is being delete, i hide the containerView that contain collectionView.

But how i know if item array is the last item being delete? whenever i try to called reloadData the containerView is not hidden and crash index out of range when it remove from the last item.

This is my collectionView inside containerView i try to delete an array of item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: TickerCell.self, for: indexPath)

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.set(message: message)
        
        cell.tickerCellCallback = { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            if strongSelf.messages.last == strongSelf.messages[indexPath.row] {
                strongSelf.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                strongSelf.hideTickerViewCallback?()
            } else {
                strongSelf.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
            }
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        return cell
    }

func reloadData() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

This is in my viewController to hide the containerView

```
private func reloadTicker() {
        tickerView.messages = homeViewModel.inboxMessages

        if homeViewModel.inboxMessages.isEmpty {
            tickerView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            tickerView.isHidden = false
            tickerView.hideTickerViewCallback = { [weak self] in
                UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0) {
                    self?.tickerView.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
        tickerView.reloadData()
    }
```

I try to compare it the last item with subscript from indexPath but the containerView is not hidden.

Comment: This is irrelevant but you do not need that outmoded `strongSelf` ballet. Just say `guard let self else {return}`.  No equals sign, not nothing.

Comment: Listen to the array from the holding view and close it when it’s empty. Or create a delegate. Or use bindings. There are many ways and the question is very vague